# Error compiling BASIC "libnotify" code

Tags: c, linux, gcc, linker, compiler-errors

```
#include <libnotify/notify.h>
#include <glib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if(argc == 3)
    {
        NotifyNotification *n;
        notify_init("Test");
        n = notify_notification_new (argv[1],argv[2], NULL, NULL);
        notify_notification_set_timeout (n, 3000); //3 seconds
        if (!notify_notification_show (n, NULL)) {
            g_error("Failed to send notification.\n");
            return 1;
        }
        g_object_unref(G_OBJECT(n));
    }else{
        g_print("Too few arguments (%d), 2 needed.\n", argc-1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Compiling the code gives me **"undefined reference to"** error:

```
shadyabhi@shadyabhi-desktop:~/c$ gcc -Wall -o test libnotify.c `pkg-config --libs --cflags glib-2.0 gtk+-2.0`
/tmp/ccA2Q6xX.o: In function `main':
libnotify.c:(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `notify_init'
libnotify.c:(.text+0x4b): undefined reference to `notify_notification_new'
libnotify.c:(.text+0x60): undefined reference to `notify_notification_set_timeout'
libnotify.c:(.text+0x71): undefined reference to `notify_notification_show'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
shadyabhi@shadyabhi-desktop:~/c$
```

I took the code from this [blog](http://ubublogger.wordpress.com/2009/04/04/using-ubuntu-jauntys-new-notification-system-notify-osd/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you forgot to pass `-lnotify` to actually link against libnotify.

Comment: ok. thanx..Perfect. But how will i know that I have to pass "-lnotify" as the argument to gcc? I mean the exact name..

Comment: If a library comes with a `.pc` file you can query `pkg-config` to find out what arguments you need to pass.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment yet, so I post this as an answer.

In a comment to the accepted question, Abhijeet Rastogi asked how to know what that argument to gcc should be, and while Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams correctly mentioned pkg-config there is more:

This magic "-lnotify" is the "-l" flag to gcc's linker appended with the library you would like to link to. When looking in /usr/lib, there is a file named libnotify.so and with "-lnotify" this file gets linked into the program.
So, to link to a library, search the respective library file in /usr/lib, note the filename, remove the "lib-" and the file extension and add that to the "-l"-flag.
Note that link order is important, so you have to include dependencies before their dependants.

Now, if there is a .pc file for the library, one can use a line like

```
gcc `pkg-config --cflags --libs libnotify` main.c ...
```

to build the program. On my system, the call to pkg-config expands to

```
-pthread -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include -lnotify -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0
```

so there is no need to explicitly deal with the glib and gtk dependencies of libnotify.